# C++: Using for loop I need to take infinite values of a point using arrays. How can I take values of point [ ] until 2 points of are equal

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

C++: Using for loop I need to take infinite values of a point using arrays. How can I take values of point [ ] until 2 points of are equal.

This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a, h, points [100];
    for(a=0 ; points [a]!= points [a-1] ; a++){
        cin>>points [a];

    }
}
```

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: When `a=0` what does `a-1` equal? What happens when you try and access a negative index? Should you not `cin >> points[0]` before the loop and start `a` at 1? What happens when `points[0] == points[2]`, they're equal but your loop won't recognize that.

Comment: Basically I want to compare two values as in if a is one value a -1 become the previous value. I'm using a=0 just for the purposes of running this for loop.

Comment: That's not what your question asks.

Comment: It's very likely (if not certain) that your program will crash. First of all, as Jonny Henly said, `points[a-1]` for a=0 won't work. Second of all, if a gets over 100, `points[a]` will be out of range and that will also make your program crash. Besides, this code won't even compile because `main` is supposed to return an `int` but you don't have any `return` statement.

Comment: How can I tell my loop to recognize these two numbers?

Comment: #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
 int a, h, points [100];
 cin>>points [0];
 for(a=1 ; points [a] != points [a-1] ; a++){
  cin>>points [a];
  
 }
}

Comment: I have now tried this. I just want to figure out my issues. I only want to calculate the loop if two consecutive numbers are equal. This is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: @HaseebArshad That's better but you still have two major mistakes: First of all, you need to be sure that a<100 before using `points[a]`, second of all, you need a `return 0;` statement at the end of your `main` function.

Comment: @DonaldDuck No, you don't need to, explicitly, `return 0;` at the end of `main`. `main` has implicit `return 0;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test if two consecutive numbers are equal, you dont need 100 elements, you need 2:

```
int points[2], counter = 1;

// Read in first point:
cin >> points[0];

// Read until we meet our condition:
do {
    // Read a point into the next part of the array.
    cin >> points[counter];
    // toggle counter between 0 and 1
    counter = (counter + 1) % 2;
// Check if we are done:
} while (points[0] != points[1]);
```

[Here is a live example.](http://ideone.com/21t7F8)

Comment: @JonnyHenly A comment from the OP: `I only want to calculate the loop if two consecutive numbers are equal.`. So i think we are good.

Comment: Ahh missed that comment